# Problemas com a função malloc

Tags: c

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca *fuzzy*, ela utiliza o operador "`new`", mas eu quis substituir pela função `malloc`. Ao fazer a substituição não obtive mais resposta no monitor serial. Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o problema?

Segue abaixo o código. O código com o operador `new` continua junto, mas comentado e logo a baixo está a equivalência com a função `malloc`.

```
#include <Fuzzy.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 3

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

double temp1=0;


// Instantiating a Fuzzy object
//Fuzzy *fuzzy = new Fuzzy();
Fuzzy *fuzzy = (Fuzzy*)malloc(sizeof(Fuzzy()));

// Instantiating a FuzzyInput object
//FuzzyInput *temperature = new FuzzyInput(1);
FuzzyInput *temperature = (FuzzyInput*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyInput(1)));
// Instantiating a FuzzySet object
//FuzzySet *cold = new FuzzySet(0, 20, 20, 25);
FuzzySet *cold = (FuzzySet*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzySet(0, 20, 20, 25)));


// Instantiating a FuzzySet object
//FuzzySet *good = new FuzzySet(23, 26, 26, 28);
FuzzySet *good = (FuzzySet*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzySet(23, 26, 26, 28)));

// Instantiating a FuzzySet object
//FuzzySet *hot = new FuzzySet(26, 40, 40, 40);
FuzzySet *hot = (FuzzySet*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzySet(26, 40, 40, 40)));



void setup() {
// Set the Serial output
Serial.begin(9600);
// Set a random seed
randomSeed(analogRead(0));

// Including the FuzzySet into FuzzyInput
temperature->addFuzzySet(cold);
// Including the FuzzySet into FuzzyInput
temperature->addFuzzySet(good);
// Including the FuzzySet into FuzzyInput
temperature->addFuzzySet(hot);
// Including the FuzzyInput into Fuzzy
fuzzy->addFuzzyInput(temperature);

// Instantiating a FuzzyOutput objects
//FuzzyOutput *decisao = new FuzzyOutput(1);
FuzzyOutput *decisao = (FuzzyOutput*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyOutput(1)));
// Instantiating a FuzzySet object
//FuzzySet *aumenta = new FuzzySet(0, 2, 2, 4);
FuzzySet *aumenta = (FuzzySet*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzySet(0, 2, 2, 4)));
// Including the FuzzySet into FuzzyOutput
decisao->addFuzzySet(aumenta);
// Instantiating a FuzzySet object
//FuzzySet *ok = new FuzzySet(2, 6, 8, 10);
FuzzySet *ok = (FuzzySet*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzySet(2, 6, 8, 10)));
// Including the FuzzySet into FuzzyOutput
decisao->addFuzzySet(ok);
// Instantiating a FuzzySet object
//FuzzySet *diminui = new FuzzySet(8, 10, 10, 12);
FuzzySet *diminui = (FuzzySet*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzySet(8, 10, 10, 12)));
// Including the FuzzySet into FuzzyOutput
decisao->addFuzzySet(diminui);
// Including the FuzzyOutput into Fuzzy
 fuzzy->addFuzzyOutput(decisao);

// Building FuzzyRule "IF temperature = cold THEN decisao = aumenta"
// Instantiating a FuzzyRuleAntecedent objects
//FuzzyRuleAntecedent *ifTemperatureCold = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
FuzzyRuleAntecedent *ifTemperatureCold = 
(FuzzyRuleAntecedent*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRuleAntecedent()));
// Creating a FuzzyRuleAntecedent with just a single FuzzySet
ifTemperatureCold->joinSingle(cold);
// Instantiating a FuzzyRuleConsequent objects
//FuzzyRuleConsequent *thenDecisaoAumenta = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
FuzzyRuleConsequent *thenDecisaoAumenta = 
(FuzzyRuleConsequent*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRuleConsequent()));
// Including a FuzzySet to this FuzzyRuleConsequent
thenDecisaoAumenta->addOutput(aumenta);
// Instantiating a FuzzyRule objects
//FuzzyRule *fuzzyRule01 = new FuzzyRule(1, ifTemperatureCold, 
thenDecisaoAumenta);
FuzzyRule *fuzzyRule01 = (FuzzyRule*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRule(1, 
ifTemperatureCold, thenDecisaoAumenta)));
// Including the FuzzyRule into Fuzzy
fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule01);

// Building FuzzyRule "IF temperature = good THEN decisao = ok"
// Instantiating a FuzzyRuleAntecedent objects
//FuzzyRuleAntecedent *ifTemperatureGood = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
FuzzyRuleAntecedent *ifTemperatureGood = 
(FuzzyRuleAntecedent*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRuleAntecedent()));
// Creating a FuzzyRuleAntecedent with just a single FuzzySet
ifTemperatureGood->joinSingle(good);
// Instantiating a FuzzyRuleConsequent objects
//FuzzyRuleConsequent *thenDecisaoOk = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
FuzzyRuleConsequent *thenDecisaoOk = 
(FuzzyRuleConsequent*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRuleConsequent()));
// Including a FuzzySet to this FuzzyRuleConsequent
thenDecisaoOk->addOutput(ok);
// Instantiating a FuzzyRule objects
//FuzzyRule *fuzzyRule02 = new FuzzyRule(2, ifTemperatureGood, thenDecisaoOk);
FuzzyRule *fuzzyRule02 = (FuzzyRule*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRule(2, ifTemperatureGood, thenDecisaoOk)));
// Including the FuzzyRule into Fuzzy
fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule02);

 // Building FuzzyRule "IF temperature = hot THEN decisao = diminui"
 // Instantiating a FuzzyRuleAntecedent objects
 //FuzzyRuleAntecedent *ifTemperatureHot = new FuzzyRuleAntecedent();
 FuzzyRuleAntecedent *ifTemperatureHot = (FuzzyRuleAntecedent*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRuleAntecedent()));
 // Creating a FuzzyRuleAntecedent with just a single FuzzySet
  ifTemperatureHot->joinSingle(hot);
 // Instantiating a FuzzyRuleConsequent objects
 //FuzzyRuleConsequent *thenDecisaoDiminui = new FuzzyRuleConsequent();
 FuzzyRuleConsequent *thenDecisaoDiminui = (FuzzyRuleConsequent*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRuleConsequent()));
 // Including a FuzzySet to this FuzzyRuleConsequent
 thenDecisaoDiminui->addOutput(diminui);
 // Instantiating a FuzzyRule objects
 //FuzzyRule *fuzzyRule03 = new FuzzyRule(3, ifTemperatureHot, thenDecisaoDiminui);
 FuzzyRule *fuzzyRule03 = (FuzzyRule*)malloc(sizeof(FuzzyRule(3, ifTemperatureHot, thenDecisaoDiminui)));
 // Including the FuzzyRule into Fuzzy
 fuzzy->addFuzzyRule(fuzzyRule03);
 }

  void loop() {
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    temp1 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

    fuzzy->setInput(1, temp1);

    // Running the Fuzzification
    fuzzy->fuzzify();

    float pertinenceOfHot = hot->getPertinence();
    float pertinenceOfGood = good->getPertinence();
    float pertinenceOfCold = cold->getPertinence();

    bool wasTheRulleFired1 = fuzzy->isFiredRule(1);
    bool wasTheRulleFired2 = fuzzy->isFiredRule(2);
    bool wasTheRulleFired3 = fuzzy->isFiredRule(3);

    // Running the Defuzzification
    float output = fuzzy->defuzzify(1);

    // Printing something
    Serial.println("Result: ");
    Serial.print("\t\t\tTemperature: ");
    Serial.println(temp1);
    Serial.print("\t\t\tDecision: ");
    if (output > 9){
    Serial.println("Diminuir a temperatura");
    }
    else if (output < 3){
    Serial.println("Aumentar a temperatura");
    }
    else{
    Serial.println("A temperatura está ok");
    }
    Serial.print("\t\t\tOutput: ");
    Serial.println(output);
    Serial.print("\t\t\tTemperature: Cold-> ");
    Serial.print(cold->getPertinence());
    Serial.print(", Good-> ");
    Serial.print(good->getPertinence());
    Serial.print(", Hot-> ");
    Serial.println(hot->getPertinence());

    Serial.print("\t\t\tRegra: 1-> ");
    Serial.print(fuzzy->isFiredRule(1));
    Serial.print(", 2-> ");
    Serial.print(fuzzy->isFiredRule(2));
    Serial.print(", 3-> ");
    Serial.println(fuzzy->isFiredRule(3));
    // wait 2 seconds
    delay(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No caso geral você não pode substituir "new" por "malloc", porque quando você usa "new" o **construtor da classe (Fuzzy neste caso) também é executado**...

Se você chama "malloc" em lugar de "new" então deveria também **executar explicitamente um código equivalente ao código do construtor da classe**.

Comment: E como eu faço um código do construtor da classe equivalente?

Comment: você tem que ver o código do construtor da classe...no caso, você queria que pegar o código do construtor da classe Fuzzy, e criar uma função tipo fuzzy_init(Fuzzy* fuzzyPtr)...na verdade, a não ser que você não possa usar C++ (por exemplo, você só pode usar C) eu acho que isso que você fez (substituir "new" por "malloc") não faz muito sentido, é perda de tempo

Comment: Não posso usar C++, por isso da alteração

Comment: Ainda não entendi como devo fazer o código equivalente ao código do construtor da classe...

Comment: você **precisa** ter acesso ao código do construtor da função Fuzzy...daí você transforma esse código C++ em uma função C, que você vai chamar logo após fazer o malloc de seu objeto Fuzzy